# Wireshark Packet Capture Data Data ACK Confusion

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I understand how acks work and windowing works. What I am not getting is why am I seeing the following behavior in packet captures

```
Client   Server
data1----->
data2----->
 <--------ack
```

When the server acks for data2, how does the client know that data1 wasnt lost? Since I don't see any ACK's for that data.

Comment: Try thinking of it as the server saying what it is still expecting.  If  it says "I got data2" its really saying "I want data3 (next one in the window)"

Comment: I meant, how does the client know that data1 didnt get lost? I see only one ACK per two segments.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a special ACK packet for each data. There is a thing called selective acknowledgements, but its not required.  Normal ACKs are part of the TCP header.  if an ACK flag is set in the flags field, then the Acknowlegment Number says data up to that point has been verified.  This flag is usually set on every packet except the first. Another field says it has space to accept a certain amount of more data.  In brief that one ACK acked both the packets you are looking at. Perhaps this will help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

Comment: @infixed You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you say "segments", I'll assume this is TCP.

Therefore, an ACK doesn't acknowledge *packets*, it acknowledges *data*.  As @infixed said, "if an ACK flag is set in the flags field, then the Acknowlegment Number says data up to that point has been verified" - if the first client TCP segment sent data with (relative) sequence numbers 0 through 24 - i.e., 25 bytes of data, starting with (relative) sequence number 0 - and the second client TCP segment sent data with (relative) sequence numbers 25-49 - i.e., 25 bytes of data, starting with (relative) sequence number 25, which is the (relative) sequence number for the first byte after the first segment - then the server can send a packet saying "I've received all data up to (relative) sequence number 49", which acknowledges the data from *both* of those packets.

In addition, as @infixed said, there's a TCP option that allows the receiver to acknowledge some but not all data in a given range.  If the first TCP segment didn't make it to the server, but the second one did, the server could use "selective acknowledgment" to say "I've received all data between (relative) sequence numbers 25 and 49", so that the client would know that it would have to retransmit the first segment but *not* the second segment.

Answer (score 0):

In brief that one ACK acked both the packets you are looking at.

There doesn't have to be a special ACK packet for each data.

While there is an enhancement to TCP called selective acknowledgements,  it is not strictly required by TCP. (But then again, most stacks these days have it)

Normal ACKs are part of the TCP header. if an ACK flag is set in the flags field, then the Acknowledgment Number says data up to that point has been verified. This flag is usually set on every packet except the first. Another field says it has space to accept a certain amount of more data.

[Wikipedia can give you more details about the TCP segment header that may make things clearer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)

Or the classic ASCII art from RFC 793

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Sequence Number                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
   | Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
   |       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                             data                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```